# How to reach the area right outside BLU's final spawn point in Barnblitz as a RED spy?

Tags: team-fortress-2, tf2-spy

I've had multiple times my teleport entrances sapped when I built them on BLU's final spawn point, but when *I* play spy, there's no obvious way to get there, so I have to resort to the revolvers. While it's still effective, it's just not the same thing.

How do you reach that ledge as a spy?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It's a fairly long, but mostly hidden process requiring a crouch jump.

[image]

The first two jumps are fairly obvious. The ledge 3 is a bit less obvious; it looks like decoration, but it's actually a platform you can land on. It's even less obvious that this ledge actually expands in the area marked 4. Once you are against the 'protection', check the leaderboard for respawn vaves, and *crouch jump* (tap jump and crouch at the same time). Sap to your heart's desire.

[Here's a video demonstration, too.](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bd1hEgxyEfQ)

There used to be an exploitable oversight right here, as this particular spawn door was *not* protected and [enemies could go through while it was open](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fRL7wTBoQQg) (but not open it themselves). This was fixed in the [July 7, 2011 Patch](https://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Barnblitz#Update_history).

Comment: Why do you ask and immediately answer?

Comment: @BlaXpirit It's encouraged to post a question you yourself researched and then answer it yourself if there's not already a similar question out there. It spreads knowledge to people who may not have already known this, without them having to ask the question themselves.

Comment: @MrSmooth: Well, this question is only about one point on one map in one game, so it's unlikely someone will be looking for it.

Comment: @BlaXpirit Well badp obviously needed help with it. So I'm assuming that somewhere out there, at least one person will read this and benefit from it. It's not like badp could be the *only* person to have wondered how to get up there.

Comment: @Blaxpirit 10 minutes ain't "immediate". It's the time I needed to write the answer, and take the video I just finished uploading. I believe this is "hidden" enough to warrant a question.

Comment: For what it is worth, I just benefitted from this.

Comment: @asmodai Somehow the engineer in me isn't too happy about that :D

Comment: Generally, you can always get back to spawn doors as all classes.  There are four in the game I can think of that you can't: cp_gorge spawn #2, the same spawn for both team in cp_5gorge, the second spawn for each team in cp_granary, and cp_dustbowl stage 3's RED A spawn door.  A similar trick to the one mentioned here can be used to reach the upper spawn door (and sniper balcony) of pl_goldrush's last RED spawn.

Comment: @Powerlord You can always get in the _other team's_ spawn door?

Comment: @badp: Back to, not in.  Being able to get in the spawn door is an exploit that I hope is unique to this map... although I recall at least one other map has this problem (Yukon, I think).